# Learing Dart , Can somebody tell me do assign this kind of function to variable

Tags: dart

```
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

void func({int a=0,@required int b}){ print("hello"); }

void main(){ void Function({int,int}) disp=func; disp(b: 1); }
```

Comment: Try `var disp=func`

Comment: I know I can do that but I want to how can I do it with function parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

```
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

void func({int a = 0, @required int b}) {
  print("hello");
}

void main() {
  void Function({int a, int b}) disp = func;
  disp(b: 1);
}
```

That is:
`void Function({int a, int b})`
Because should be specified named parameters in (`Function`) type declaration.

Comment: The best thanks is the accepted answer (accept and upvote).